# How lsb module affects system, and can be made available to the system?

Tags: modules

```
aks@aks-K55VD:~$ lsb_release -a  
No LSB modules are available.  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS  
Release:    12.04  
Codename:   precise
```

used the command `lsb_release -a`
and found 'No LSB modules are available'

LSB->http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base

what does that mean by the unavailability of this module
and how can they be made available to my system?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Since there are no lsb modules installed in your machine, you get that message.

You can install the lsb modules using the command

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-core
```

After installation, when you run the same command you wont see the message saying 'No LSB modules are available'

`lsb_release -a` will display some basic info about to which LSB specifications your system/OS complies with.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also see this bug report - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lsb/+bug/66914