# Unable to boot Ubuntu 14.04 after upgrading

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade

I successfully upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 with `sudo do-release-upgrade`, and after that with `lsb_release -a` I received this message:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

but after I powered off, I could not boot my system.

Comment: Welcome to [Ask Ubuntu!](https://askubuntu.com/), try this one https://askubuntu.com/q/230766/856659