# What are lsb modules? And why do I need to install them?

Tags: 18.04, lsb-release

When I used the command lsb_release, System threw an error that "No lsb modules are available".
So what are they and why to install them to get my system info(through command lsb_release)?

Comment: See the [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lsb/+bug/66914).

Comment: Who say you "need to install them"?

Comment: Use `lsb_release -cdir`. Plain `lsb_release` is not supposed to work on Ubuntu.

Comment: dupe: https://askubuntu.com/questions/230766/how-lsb-module-affects-system-and-can-be-made-available-to-the-system

Comment: Thanks @VeeJay. I got why it is showing the error. But I didn't get what are these modules!

Comment: @mikewhatever in the below link, one suggests to install for removing the error.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/230766/how-lsb-module-affects-system-and-can-be-made-available-to-the-system

Comment: Thanks @AlexP. This command worked.
However, in the link provided by VeeJay I saw "lsb_release -a" also worked(but it showed the error too with the required result).

Answer (score 0):

After trying lsb_release -cdir and seeing that it worked, I just set it up as an alias with

alias lsb_release='lsb_release -cdir'

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, so doing this made sense for me.